# Gatling. How to send POST multipart/form-data without file

Tags: multipartform-data, gatling

I try to send POST multipart/form-data but without attached file. It's like the client sends sign up form with email + password and without avatar file(this field isn't required).

```
HTTP request:
POST https://.../profile/user/own
headers=
Authorization: bearer eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.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.APWse9P8SIJtDMMay8UTT9CN_JEvSIRaznn8JALcYfxz107IaL5ezwEJfIEDBb9_WEDeVKvpjI1eUmiYBQiOcF5LkIPhpww_8vaSbWvWP3Tkg21QQceNEZwnjucMc6Doj1YNlx3iOs03Mv8zmOJZ2S1acz5sVj5cK_ufrItG7Ic_-bbpW67Byl1vNgbTgaJoGMRAgqfCxKpAVpxMFqNw3F8FMKe0dm-uYmJwpKlWVg4sEUOW7LSZ6wr3c5XgBHXVvTzVFb0sJyhFkw9W1nrMSJTxJqsaVGEzIe01qhQZasbRkMxC32XXlFzpGSmBDJpdWpTD3pUXrIhD4v15PWt3wg
accept: */*
host: api.dev.psychicbook.net
content-type: multipart/form-data
content-length: 108
formBody=
userData: {"email":"automation.tku1fin9av3@test.com","nickname":"5SkHTB0EVs"}
=========================
HTTP response:
status=
500 
headers= 
Server: nginx/1.17.10
Date: Mon, 28 Sep 2020 10:11:53 GMT
Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Connection: keep-alive
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET,POST,PUT,PATCH,DELETE,OPTIONS
Access-Control-Max-Age: 3600
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type, Authorization
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
X-Application-Context: gateway-service:develop:8765
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
Pragma: no-cache
Expires: 0
X-Frame-Options: DENY
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=15724800; includeSubDomains

body=
{"timestamp":1601287913987,"status":500,"error":"Internal Server Error","exception":"org.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartException","message":"Could not parse multipart servlet request; nested exception is java.io.IOException: org.apache.tomcat.util.http.fileupload.FileUploadException: the request was rejected because no multipart boundary was found","path":"/profile/user/own"}
```

There is a special method for file uploading -> .formUpload("file", "image.jpg"), but I don't want to send any file.
If I make the same with Insomnia or anoter REST client, everything is OK, and it looks like:

```
HttpResponse<String> response = Unirest.post("https://.../profile/user/own")
  .header("authorization", "bearer eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.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.bW7F65elarJNQ9RkfIJcH0uq9Og0ue8TXNZ7Gh_FFCdj_c8SVHlPXwu-nEoZZSTVk3gBB2I_hw8MqPfCZVZrlAlzyIfAcyuQ1WRgRH5-xVzYej3XqBEADuCjBabcO87LoPwz_vYCT3JZVhNZHcDMOkQ429dg0HdKeSBd6qJaPYCgWgq529b9-wnufNBx9LHyaTYLWZC5nMfmDbyep3sc2_q6YzqKMMH5a-s1SmOgQpKbCNyCx7gui3tiYqQh21zMN-PhtkRNAD78awzpIpZhuZTF-AbrQkI6J1Yvsg59AYkZZVBd5gyCSopydquezf7xaAc3Ot2L-DubGzWwr2u9gA")
  .header("content-type", "multipart/form-data; boundary=---011000010111000001101001")
  .body("-----011000010111000001101001\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"userData\"\r\n\r\n{\"email\":\"automation.tku1fin9av3@test.com\",\"nickname\":\"qatest5\"}\r\n-----011000010111000001101001\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"file\"\r\n\r\n\r\n-----011000010111000001101001--\r\n")
  .asString();
```

How can I make the same but with Gatling?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. I have some entries with, and some without files. Both need to be uploaded using body parts.

When i set one fields using StringBodyPart it worked for me:

```
val uploadDocument = doIfEqualsOrElse(session => session("file").as[String], "") {
        // executed if the session value stored in "myKey" starts with "admin"
        exec(
          http("upload: ${title}")
            .post(
              clientPortalUrl + "/customerportal/api/documents"
            )
            .headers(multipartUploadHeaders)
            //if we do not call formUpload() we need set one field using StringBodyPart, the rest will follow.
            .bodyPart(StringBodyPart("title", "${title}")).asMultipartForm
            .formParam("documentType", "${documentType}")
            .formParam("accountId", "${accountId}")
            .formParam("period", "${period}")
            .formParam("endDate", "${endDate}")
            .formParam("signer", "${signer}")
            .formParam("nexusRecipient", "${nexusRecipient}")
            .formParam("vatFiscalEntityDivision", "${vatFiscalEntityDivision}")
            .formParam("editor", "${editor}")
            .formParam("repeatable", "${repeatable}")
            .requestTimeout(5.minutes)
            .check(status.is(201))
            .check(jsonPath("$.title").exists)
        )
      } {
        exec(
          http("upload: ${title}")
            .post(
              clientPortalUrl + "/customerportal/api/documents"
            )
            .headers(multipartUploadHeaders)
            .formParam("title", "${title}")
            .formParam("documentType", "${documentType}")
            .formParam("accountId", "${accountId}")
            .formParam("period", "${period}")
            .formParam("endDate", "${endDate}")
            .formParam("signer", "${signer}")
            .formParam("nexusRecipient", "${nexusRecipient}")
            .formParam("vatFiscalEntityDivision", "${vatFiscalEntityDivision}")
            .formParam("editor", "${editor}")
            .formParam("repeatable", "${repeatable}")
            .formUpload("files[]", "${file}")
            .requestTimeout(5.minutes)
            .check(status.is(201))
            .check(jsonPath("$.title").exists)
        )
      }
```